# Problems with a footer

Tags: footer, erase

I have a question for you guys..
I'm making a website directly hosted by Wordpress, and I would like to clear the footer. How could I get to the Root folder and modify it, directly from the web? 
The theme is called "Visual".

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If this is a standard installation, look at /wp-content/themes/Visual/footer.php